# Linear transformation which maps matrix to matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T :M_n (\mathbb{R})\to M_n (\mathbb{R})$ is linear transformation   from vector space  $M_n (\mathbb{R})$   of all $n×n$ Matrices  defined by 
$T (Q)=QP $ for each $P$ in $M_n (\mathbb{R})$, for   some $Q$ in $M_n (\mathbb{R})$.

My Question  is  what  is  the  similarty  between $T$ and $Q$ ?
 Are   minimal  polynomials  of $T$ and $Q$  same?

Is rank and nullity same ?
 And  eigen values  ?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2233959/characteristic-polynomial-of-tm-n-mathbbf-rightarrow-m-n-mathbbf/2234005#2234005

Answer (score 2):

Per the discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)), the matrix of your transformation $T$ will be $I \otimes Q$, where $\otimes$ denotes the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

It is notable that the following two properties hold:

- For each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ of $Q$ with multiplicity $k$, $\lambda_i$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with multiplicity $nk$
- For any polynomial $p$, we have $p(I \otimes Q) = I \otimes p(Q)$.  Equivalently, verify that $[p(T)](M) = [p(Q)]M$ for each $M \in M_n(\Bbb R)$.

It follows that:

- $\chi_T(t) = [\chi_Q(t)]^n$ ($\chi_M(t)$ denote the characteristic polynomial of $M$)
- $m_T(t) = m_Q(t)$ ($m_M(t)$ denotes the minimal polynomial of $M$)
- $\operatorname{rank}(T) = n\operatorname{rank}(Q)$
- $\dim \ker(T) = n\, \dim \ker (Q)$